# Can VMware utilize an SSD?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, ssd, vmware

I have installed Mac OS X 10.12 in VMware Player. The installation was in an SSD, but in the settings it shows only options to add Hard Disk (SATA).

Also Mac sees this as an HDD.

[image]

If the guest Mac is utilizing the SSD or it just performing as if it in a normal SATA HDD? If so is there any way to let mac utilize the SSD in VMware?

VMware Workstation 12 Player 12.5.2

Comment: I'm pretty sure VirtualBox has a setting to expose a virtual disk as a SSD. VMWare might very well (and probably does) have something similar.

Comment: Within the configuration file.  It should be as simple as using, `scsiX:Y.virtualSSD = 1`, and then your virtual HDD will be a virtual SSD.  You didn't provide which version of VMWare Player your using.  So you will have to verify yourself if your version supports this configuration option.  I can confirm OS X supports SSD reporting for SATA devices.

Comment: @Ramhound i am using vmware 12.5.2. So if this going to perform well if i install mac (vmdk) on a ssd or its same as installing mac (vmdk) on a hdd? Thanks

Comment: VMware is the company name. You’re most likely using VMware Fusion.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i am using VMware® Workstation 12 Player

Comment: @DanielB - VMWare Workstation Player doesn't exist on OS X, which is how I know, he isn't using a OS X host.

Comment: @rakibtg - At the end of the day the physical device is a SSD.  You will have to perform benchmarks to determine if it will perform "well" or not.